# Altium: Export/Package Read-Only PCB or Project

Tags: pcb, altium, design

I'm looking to export an altium PCB or full project but would like it to be "read-only" so that whomever I'm sending it to cannot edit it without my knowledge. They're looking to do a more in-depth analysis than just the gerbers/fab/assy files.
Has anyone had experience exporting read-only projects with Altium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to make your project read only in Altium, to avoid accidental changes you should simply lock all your components and features.

There are alternatives that I have used

1. Send a stripped down design or only the PCB file and a reference schematic
2. Send odb++ or an exported CAD data (e.g. legacy ascii fileformat) that makes it less trivial to pretend to be you while providing more data than gerbers and basic assembly data .
3. Find consultants you trust to  respect your IP,

Comment: Thanks, that was going to be an option: Just send the PCB without any traces so that it couldn't be produced without having to reroute it. What I ended up doing is sending the schematic and assembly file to them in pdf format so they could "ctrl-f" to find where each component is on the PCBA. Plus a 3D file (Step and PDF). Seems they were content with that. Thank you!

Comment: ODB++ or pick and place data along with Gerber is usually sufficient for assembler to program the SMT .